# Scrapy ends after first result

Tags: scrapy

I've been looking around and cant find the answer I'm looking for. I got my crawler (scrapy) to return the results close to what i'm looking for. So What I'm trying to do now is get it to pull the multiple results from the page. Currently it pulls the first one and stops. If I take off the extract_first() then it pulls all the data and groups them. So looking for one of 2 answers that would work.

1) continue crawling results and not ending
2) ungroup each item onto a new line of results

Here is my code:

```
    import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from urlparse import urlparse
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
#from scrappy.http import HtmlResponse

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ziprecruiter"

    def start_requests(self):
        allowed_domains = ["https://www.ziprecruiter.com/"]     
        urls = [
            'https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?search=operations+manager&location=San+Francisco%2C+CA'
            ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for houses in response.xpath('/html/body'):
            yield {

                'Job_title:' : houses.xpath('.//span[@class="just_job_title"]//text()[1]').extract_first(),
                'Company:' : houses.xpath('.//a[@class="t_org_link name"]//text()[1]').extract_first(),
                'Location:' : houses.xpath('.//a[@class="t_location_link location"]//text()[1]').extract_first(),
                'FT/PT:' : houses.xpath('.//span[@class="data_item"]//text()[1]').extract_first(),

                'Link' : houses.xpath('/html/body/main/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[4]/div[1]/button[1]/text()').extract_first(),
                'Link' : houses.xpath('.//a/@href[1]').extract_first(),
                'pay' : houses.xpath('./section[@class="perks_item"]/span[@class="data_item"]//text()[1]').extract_first()

                }
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT::
After more research I redefined the container to crawl in and that gives me all the right answers. Now my question is how do I get each item on the page instead of only the first result... it just doesn't loop. Heres my code:

```
    import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from urlparse import urlparse
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
#from scrappy.http import HtmlResponse

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ziprecruiter"

    def start_requests(self):
        allowed_domains = ["https://www.ziprecruiter.com/"]     
        urls = [
            'https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?search=operations+manager&location=San+Francisco%2C+CA'
            ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for houses in response.xpath('/html/body/main/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div[2]'):
            yield {

                'Job_title:' : houses.xpath('.//span[@class="just_job_title"]//text()').extract(),
                'Company:' : houses.xpath('.//a[@class="t_org_link name"]//text()').extract(),
                'Location:' : houses.xpath('.//a[@class="t_location_link location"]//text()').extract(),
                'FT/PT:' : houses.xpath('.//span[@class="data_item"]//text()').extract(),
                'Link' : houses.xpath('.//a/@href').extract(),
                'pay' : houses.xpath('./section[@class="perks_item"]/span[@class="data_item"]//text()').extract()

                }
```

Comment: I only get a single div element from the xpath you've provided, which explains why the houses loop only executes once.  To me, seems like something is wrong with your xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you should use this xpath instead:

```
//div[@class="job_content"]
```

As that is the class of the div you're looking for.  When I execute it for this page, I get 20 div elements returned.  However, you might want to add some more filtering to the xpath query just in case there are other divs with that class name that you don't want to parse.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed it to this. Looks like that helped alot. Will do some more testing real fast but I think this is the resolve!

Comment: hey sorry to bother but I had the same issue on another crawler. Could you link me to more info on finding "successful" containers?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by containers.

Comment: I mean how I would go about finding the correct xpath for the allowed areas in this example how you gave me the //div[@class=job_content"]. since im still new its a bit confusing and cant seem to ask the right question on google searches :/